# Can text within a sequence of elements be controlled in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have this valid tag:

```
<Element>
   <SubElement/>
   Some text directly here.
</Element>
```

Or this also should be valid:

```
<Element>
   Some text directly here.
</Element>
```

But this should not be valid:

```
<Element>
   Some text directly here.
   <SubElement/>
   Some text directly here.
</Element>
```

Also this should not be:

```
<Element>
   <SubElement/>
</Element>
```

***Is there a way to add text nodes to a sequence in XSD?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a reasonable request, but unfortunately you cannot restrict the position of text in that manner using XSD.

You can use `xs:complexType/@mixed` to allow elements mixed with text, but you cannot represent the restrictions you request; `<SubElement/>` would have to be allowed to appear anywhere within the text.

Comment: Thanks. Is there way to restrict the `Element` to contain a text node *OR* a `SubElement` node?

Comment: No, you'd think `xs:choice` might be used for that, but unfortunately XSD doesn't have as orthogonal of a view of text and elements as would be needed for that to work.  If you can use XSD 1.1, you could probably construct an `xs:assert` over mixed content to achieve your text node *OR* `SubElement` constraint.